# Google Calendar Add Events anonymously Via Page Form

Tags: php, web-applications, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a website that I'm integrating with a Google calendar.  I want to allow users to add events to this calendar, but not directly.  I've got a form setup on the page that can add events to the calendar presently, but you have to be logged in to use that form.  Is there a way to authorize the webpage itself, or put the auth token in the code so that you don't have to be logged in to add an event?  All I get on the Google developer site is a bunch of "Google knows best" brow beating about how it's a bad idea from a security stand point, but no real answers.  Has anyone ever done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service account and store your private key as a .p12 file.

Here's Googles Info on Service Accounts: [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount)

What you need to do with your service account: [Next Steps](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts)

I have the same question as you did; I am in the process of creating a script to auto authenticate the user to add an event to a google calendar (as a background process) ...using the data captured in the form for the calendar event details & time/date.

So far I have managed to POST the form details to a new file that loads after the form's submit button is clicked. Currently the page will then ask the user to Accept ("Are you ok with this app having access to your calendar settings?: Yes, No?")... Then It will allow the user to confirm the details to submit, After confirmation, user is redirected to the homepage. A new event created.

(If you want to see my current progress take a look at my youtube vid: **www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pU_RvpGqx0&hd=1** Note: I have updated my script since.)

Good Luck!

Josh.